# My program works with array::forEach but not with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, foreach

Consider the following codes.

## Code with an `array.forEach` call.

```
var data = ['a', 'b',  'c'];
var all_combinations = [];

function recursiveGetAllCombinations(data_cursor = 0, combination_being_constructed = []) {

    data.forEach(function(element) {
    combination_being_constructed[data_cursor] = element;
    if(data_cursor == data.length - 1) {
        all_combinations.push(combination_being_constructed);      
    } else {
        recursiveGetAllCombinations(data_cursor + 1, combination_being_constructed.slice());
    }
  });

}

recursiveGetAllCombinations();
console.log(all_combinations);
```

### Output

It `console.log` the correct output (more precisely, the *almost* correct results, since there are redundance : each element is repeated 3 times - however it should not be the case, because the `forEach(element)` changes the value of `element` from an iteration to another, obviously.....).

```
(27) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0
:
(3) ["a", "a", "c"]
1
:
(3) ["a", "a", "c"]
2
:
(3) ["a", "a", "c"]
3
:
(3) ["a", "b", "c"]
4
:
(3) ["a", "b", "c"]
5
:
(3) ["a", "b", "c"]
6
:
(3) ["a", "c", "c"]
7
:
(3) ["a", "c", "c"]
8
:
(3) ["a", "c", "c"]
9
:
(3) ["b", "a", "c"]
10
:
(3) ["b", "a", "c"]
11
:
(3) ["b", "a", "c"]
12
:
(3) ["b", "b", "c"]
13
:
(3) ["b", "b", "c"]
14
:
(3) ["b", "b", "c"]
15
:
(3) ["b", "c", "c"]
16
:
(3) ["b", "c", "c"]
17
:
(3) ["b", "c", "c"]
18
:
(3) ["c", "a", "c"]
19
:
(3) ["c", "a", "c"]
20
:
(3) ["c", "a", "c"]
21
:
(3) ["c", "b", "c"]
22
:
(3) ["c", "b", "c"]
23
:
(3) ["c", "b", "c"]
24
:
(3) ["c", "c", "c"]
25
:
(3) ["c", "c", "c"]
26
:
(3) ["c", "c", "c"]
length
:
27
```

## The same code, with a `for` loop.

```
var data = ['a', 'b',  'c'];
var all_combinations = [];

function recursiveGetAllCombinations(data_cursor = 0, combination_being_constructed = []) {

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    combination_being_constructed[data_cursor] = data[i];
    if(data_cursor == data.length - 1) {
        all_combinations.push(combination_being_constructed);      
    } else {
        recursiveGetAllCombinations(data_cursor + 1, combination_being_constructed.slice());
    }
  }

}

recursiveGetAllCombinations();
console.log(all_combinations);
```

### Output

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0
:
(3) ["a", "a", "c"]
1
:
(3) ["a", "a", "c"]
2
:
(3) ["a", "a", "c"]
length
:
3
```

## My questions

I have two questions.

1) First, why the code with `forEach` does display three times each element ?

2) The second : why both programs differ in what results are displayed ?

Comment: One major concern: you have not defined `i` as a local variable, so it is shared in the recursive calls. As soon as one loop ends, *all* of them in the recursive tree will end. Do `for (let i = ` ... etc.

Comment: Thank you, you should write this as an answer :) However, it answers my 2nd question , not the first (which concerns both the ` for( let i) ` and the `forEach` thus

Comment: It displays three times because `if(data_cursor == data.length - 1)` doesn't vary with the forEach, and there are three items in the data array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues:

**The same array gets repeated**

This is because you do not take a copy of the array when iterating. You do `slice` in the recursive call, but that is not enough. When you are at the deepest recursion level, you first write "a" in the last entry of the array, push it on the results, and then write "b" in the *same* memory location. So you actually change the *already pushed* data, while also adding it again. Now you have twice the same result. The same happens when putting "c": you change the two previously added results. They are all three the same array.

So apply the `slice` (only) to the argument passed to the `push` method:

```
all_combinations.push(combination_being_constructed.slice());
```

**The second code does not produce many results**

This is because in JavaScript, if you do not explicitly declare a variable with the `var`, `let`, or `const` keyword, it gets *implicitly* declared on the **global** scope, and thus, shared across your recursive function calls. At the deepest recursion level it iterates to the end of the array, and *all* loops that were pending in the recursion tree will now also exit, as they all share the same `i` variable.

Fix this by declaring `i` in the function scope (or block scope). Use:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

One easy way to detect if you have done this by accident is to put `"use strict";` at the top of your code file or functions and it will throw a console error rather than implicitly declaring the variable on the global scope.

Comment: `"use strict";` would have caught the implicit global variable